# Structured Data Testing Tool showing JSON-LD syntax error: "value, object or array expected"

Tags: json, syntax-error, json-ld

I have inputted my businesses name and it's still not excepting it and I have no idea why.

[image: JSON-LD]

[image: Google SDTT error message]

Comment: Your quotes around the value of "name" ("Demeanour Customs") is not a normal double quote, change that and you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix straight quotes (`"`) and smart quotes (`“`, `”`). Smart quotes look better in English writing and are used in professionally-printed books, but most programming languages don’t recognize them. By default, the quotation-mark key on your keyboard makes straight quotes, but a lot of word processors know that more people write prose than code and replace them with smart quotes; you always use a text editor or IDE which doesn’t do that when writing code.

In particular, the value of the `name` key is enclosed in smart quotes, and the value of the `url` key starts with a straight quote but ends with a smart quote.